# Upload folder onto virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, scp, google-cloud-storage

I created a VM instance on the Compute Engine in a Google Cloud project. I want to upload a folder from my computer's local storage onto the boot disk of the virtual machine.

I tried using the `scp` command in the command line interface of my computer by typing `scp /file/path/name external-ip-address-of-server:.` But then I got the error`Permission denied (publickey). lost connection`

I'm also aware that the `wget` command can be used to download a file from the internet onto a computer. I thought of using this, but that would require putting my folder online as a download link, which I don't know how to do.

What's the best way to put a folder from local storage onto the boot disk of a virtual machine?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Fixing the permission (denied error) is probably the easiest way to go. If you can successfully login using ssh, then scp can be made to work in the same way as SSH. Just like ssh, scp needs username and the SSH (private) key in order to connect to `external-ip-address-of-server`. If you don't specify username and the SSH key, then the defaults are applied. The default username is the username of your PC / laptop that you've logged-in. The default SSH key is `~/.ssh/id_rsa` in certain operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is probably [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

A possible command line might be:

```
rsync -av /file/path/name external-ip-address-of-server:
```

Rsync uses `ssh` as its default transport, so before it will work easily for you, it looks like you need to get your `ssh` logins working.  But that's another question, and one that StackExchange probably already has an answer for.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is

`gcloud compute scp --recurse [folder_name] your_instance:/path/to/copy/`

You can find reference here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Storage Buckets to store folders. This way you can copy the same folders to different VMs.

Basic command is [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil). If you want to copy a file use a [gustil cp](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp). For syncing folders you can use [gsutil rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)

Example of copying data from local machine to a bucket:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r data . gs://mybucket/data
```

Example for copying from bucket to vm, connect to VM then:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r data gs://mybucket/data .
```

-m is for multithread sync

-r is to look into subfolders

Comment: I actually do have a Storage Bucket in my project, but the problem is it's not the same as the boot disk. Is there a way to move a folder from the storage bucket onto the boot disk?

Comment: Sure, you just need to run 'df -h', see where boot disk is mounted and cd in there.
It is recommended to create a new folder in the boot disk when doing rsync.